# Binomial identity for bijection $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, integers

In a book I'm currently reading it is said (without proof) that, for an enumeration $d$ of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ defined by
$$d(0)=(0,0),\ d(1)=(0,1),\ d(2)=(1,0),\ d(3)=(0,2),\ d(4)=(1,1),\ d(5)=(2,0),\ d(6)=(0,3),\ \cdots$$
the inverse function can be written as
$$c(x,y)=\binom{x+y+1}2+x.$$
Out of curiosity, I was trying to find a combinatorial argumentation, but I haven't succeeded so far. Maybe one of you can help.

Comment: In the book there's (hopefully) a diagram of how that enumeration works; you start at the origin and draw diagonal lines farther and farther out.  When you've reached a point (x,y) you've completed x+y diagonals and used x additional points on the next one.  The number of points in the triangle will work out to be that binomial coefficient (look up 'triangular numbers' if you don't know about those).  I don't think using a binomial coefficient was meant to indicate you should prove it combinatorially, it's just a quicker way of writing the formula for the area of that triangle.

Answer (score 1):

I largely agree with **Lance Sackless** in the comments, but there is a *somewhat* combinatorial interpretation of the formula related to the picture that he describes. For a fixed integer $k\ge 0$ there are $k+1$ integer lattice points on the line $x+y=k$. Pick any two of them, say $p=\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $q=\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$, where $x_0<x_1$; these two points uniquely determine one integer lattice point in the triangle bounded by the axes and the line $x+y=k$, namely, the point $\langle x_0,y_1\rangle$ below $p$ and to the left of $q$. Each integer lattice point in that triangle can be specified in this way, so there are $\binom{k+1}2$ integer lattice points in that triangle.

Thus, if $p=\langle x,y\rangle$ is any integer lattice point on that line, there are $\binom{k+1}2=\binom{x+y+1}2$ integer lattice points in the triangle below it that get enumerated first, and it’s the $x$-th point on that line to be enumerated, since the enumeration along that line proceeds from (upper) left to (lower) right, so $p$ gets the number $\binom{x+y+1}2+x$.